# Fix text default in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When i set a default:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIkjI.png)

I have:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfqFF.png)

I want result is [] not '[]'
How i can fix?

Answer (score 0):

It works as intended, the default will be set to what is inside of `''`
[image]

[image]

And when you insert new row without defining `something` column it will still have default value you want.

[image]

[image]

That means that SQL ignores the `''` and its only use is to show that its DateType is a TEXT and not an INT.

[image]

Here, when we changed something to DataType of INT and gave it default value 232 it doesn't have a single quote.